# How can we change the icon of microsoft teams while working with react

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-teams

Integrate share via ms teams features in my react js web app.
The below solution is working but I need to remove and add a launcher every time to see the ms ICON, also I want to change that icon and give the same functionality to my UI component

```
    const msTeamsLauncherUrl = 'https://teams.microsoft.com/share/launcher.js';

 const handleclick = () => {
                        const ele = document.getElementById('teams-share');
                        if (ele) {
                            document.body.removeChild(ele);
                        }

                        if (document.querySelectorAll(`[src="${msTeamsLauncherUrl}"]`).length === 0) {
                            const script = document.createElement('script');
                            if (script) {
                                script.src = msTeamsLauncherUrl;
                                script.id = 'teams-share';
                                document.body.appendChild(script);
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Are you developing any Teams app? If yes could you please share repro steps to try at our end.

Comment: Not a teams app, just a web app, and adding a share via teams feature

Comment: Could you please share repro steps to try at our end?

Comment: Could you please go through below doc if its help you in any way
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/share-to-teams-from-web-apps

Comment: Thanks, but I have already gone through that and there is no provision to change the icon or hide the default icon, is there any other way except patching css ?

Comment: There doesn't seems to be any way to change the icon or hide the default icon.